# Writing Standalone server which can serve multiple clients simultaneously using reslet framework

Tags: restlet-2.0

I am trying to do a project (virtual classroom) which contains  a server and multiple clients.
From server I should be able to handle video streaming,authentication,chat etc.. when multiple instances of clients send requests. Please guide me how can I use Restlet framework for this project?

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement a RESTful application using Restlet, you need to begin by implementing several entities for the server side:

- REST resources (classes extending the ServerResource class) that will contains processing.
- Restlet application that will define how to access your resources.
- Restlet server to serve REST HTTP request.

I recommend you to have a look at the hello world sample application from the Restlet website at the address: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet.html. For the complete application, you can focus on the "Java SE client" at the first time.

In a first time, you can skip authentication since it can be added after on both client and server sides on ClientResource and within Application.

Don't hesitate if you have more questions!
Thierry